# Changing Checkbox color if in-correct

Tags: php

I've got this HTML and PHP code:

```
    <?php
require_once("include/membersite_config.php");
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
if($fgmembersite->Login())
{
$fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login-home.php");
}
}
?>

<form id='login'  action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 15px; right: 120px;">
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<input type='text' name='username' class="formlogin" placeholder='Username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username') ?>' maxlength="20" />
<span id='login_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
<input type='password' class="formlogin" placeholder="Password" name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
<span id='login_password_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<input type='submit' style='position: absolute; top: 18px; right: 45px;' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
<!--<div class='short_explanation'><a href='reset-pwd-req.php'>Forgot Password?</a></div>-->
<div><span class='error'><?php echo $fgmembersite->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
</form>
```

If the username and/or password box is empty, a message will appear, notifying the user. How do I make the empty box(es) change to the color red, if they're empty **after the user clicked submit**?

Comment: There are no checkboxes in your form. Did you mean text boxes?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't mean checkboxes, I meant the text input boxes.

Comment: It would be easier to do this using client-side validation with Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, if possible would you be able to post an example?

Comment: How does your `login()` function gets called?

Comment: I'll edit my post and include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it on the client with Javascript.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    function validate(e) {
        var username = document.getElementById('username');
        if (username.value.trim() == '') {
            username.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            username.style.backgroundColor = null;
        }
        var password = document.getElementById('password');
        if (password.value.trim() == '') {
            password.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            e.preventDefault();
        }else {
            password.style.backgroundColor = null;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('submit', validate);
}
</script>
```

`e.preventDefault()` prevents the form from submitting when one of the validation errors occurs.

Comment: Should I remove my PHP scripts?

Comment: Of course not. You still need them to do the actual login.

Comment: And you can't depend on client-side validation, since the user can bypass it. If they do, they just won't get the colored boxes.

Comment: Oh right. Just a couple of questions, how do I get both boxes to light up red if they're empty? Is it possible also to make the boxes light up red if the password is in-correct?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to distinguish between an incorrect username and incorrect password. It makes guessing usernames and passwords easier, because then they know when they got the username correct and only have to try to crack the password.

Comment: My code will light up both boxes if they're empty. Why do you think it stops with the first error?

Comment: Hi Barmar, sorry for the late, late response. If the username value is empty when they click submit, the username box lights up red, but then the page refreshes and the textbox goes back to it's normal color (white).

Comment: I was missing the `e` parameter in the `validate()` function, so `e.preventDefault()` was failing. Try it now.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't notice my mistake first. Didn't it cause an error in the Javascript console?

Comment: I'm using x10 Hosting as my web host, so it doesn't usually display Javascript errors.

Comment: Javascript errors are displayed in the browser console, they don't depend on the web host.